# Diverged Branches in GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I tried to sync my local repository with the remote one on the GitHub site, but I keep getting an error. However, I don't really know how to fix it.

Can someone help me figure out what's going on?  I'm new to using GitHub, and it doesn't make much sense to me.

Here's a picture of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you did before running `git status` that caused you to generate the merge conflicts. Why does your remote branch have changes that aren't in your local branch? Are you sharing your branch with someone else, and they pushed new code to the remote? Or did you amend or rebase any of your local commits that you had previously pushed to your remote branch?

Answer (score 0):

There were changes to your branch on the remote repo. Did you try to `pull`, `merge`, or `rebase` the changes to your branch on the remote? Any one of those operations would generate the merge conflicts that you're seeing.

If you actually wanted to `pull`, `merge`, or `rebase` the new changes from the remote into your local branch, then all you have to do is fix the merge conflicts, then push.

Why do you have changes on the remote? Are you sharing your branch with someone else, and they pushed new changes there? Or did you amend or rebase your existing commits locally? If you did, that would cause conflicts with any code that you've already pushed to your remote as well.